# Auto Apply credits at checkout

Tags: commerce, userpoints

I am using commerce_userpoints which allows the use of credit to discount the amount at checkout of a product.

Right now the user needs to do this manually however I would like to automate this.

Any clue on how can I get this done ?

Comment: what ?!!! 
>user needs to do this manually however I would like to automate this.
what you want? you want what happened ? discount from order with user_points,but how much of it?

Answer (score 4):

Use rules. When the order is completed, use the actions contained in the  `userpoints_rules` submodule to manage your userpoints. You might choose the "When an order has been paid in full" or you could just watch for orders moving in status to "Completed."